# Way to express a number as sum of other numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Consider a number $n$ and a set $x$ where $x$ = { collection of y where n%y=0} and length of set x be $k$ and also set $x$ need **not** to have all factors of n **.  Consider $a$ $=$ $\sum_{i=1}^k y_i⋅s_i$,
where $s_i$ are coefficients for $y_i$,where $s_i$ $>$ $-1$ for all $i$ between [0,k].
the criterion  for number to be good is such that n $ < $ $a$ but for all i this should hold  $ s_i$ $ > $ $ 0$ ,$a$ $-$ $y_i$ $ < $ $n$.

for example:

$x$ = {2,5}
and $n$ $=$ 10,then  set $s$ $ = $ {3,1}
which satisfy the criteria.

Given such a set $x$ and number $n$ is it possible to form a set $s$, where set s is set of collection of $s_i$, that is, is it possible to form a number a such that the given criteria holds or to say $n$ is good?

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  Please edit for clarity.  In the formula for $a$, should that be the sum over $y_i\cdot s_i$?  And your problem statement does not refer to any set $s$.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: If $n=10$ then the set of all $y$ such that $a\%y=0$ is the set $\{1,2,5,10\}$, not $\{2,5\}$.

Comment: Unfortunately the edits aren't making it any clearer. There's a contradiction now. $n\%y=0$ exactly if $y$ is a factor of $n$ (at least if you're using $\%$ in the usual sense of the remainder operation). But then you write that the set $x$ defined as the collection of all such $y$ need to have all factors of $n$; that's a contradiction. Please think this through and then post a coherent update to the question; otherwise people will quickly lose interest.

Comment: they never said ALL y, which leads me to believe that what they meant is a set containing SOME factors of n